# How to resolve MongoDb UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.3zwxl.mongodb.net?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am able to start the server but cannot able to run the web app as localhost getting the below error

```
Server started on port 3000
(node:13052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: queryTxt ETIMEOUT cluster0.3zwxl.mongodb.net
    at QueryReqWrap.onresolve [as oncomplete] (dns.js:203:19)
(node:13052) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1) 
(node:13052) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled 
will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Here is my url

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxx:vikas@cluster0.3zwxl.mongodb.net/xxxxxx",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology: true});

Moreover the webapp is not loading and getting "This site can’t be reached"

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue today itself.. and i found some of the solutions mentioned below:

1. Changing the DNS
2. Adding current IP to whitelist section of your mongodb
3. Connecting with the same network that you've configured with

Solution No. 3 worked for me... as soon as i connected to my network which i had configured with i got console Connected to database... and as soon as i change my network again i got the error

[you can see the image when i connected back to previous network it was working but when i changed my network i got the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jY6Op.png)

Answer (score 0):

I had fixed my issue

```
mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://xxxxxxxx:xxxxxxxx@cluster0.3zwxl.mongodb.net/xxxxxx?retryWrites=true&w=majority",{useNewUrlParser:true,useUnifiedTopology: true});

mongoose.connection.on("connected",()=>{
console.log("Mongoose connected");
})
```

Answer (score 0):

better approach for multiple connections for future use

```
    const connectDB = async () => {
        try {
          await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
          });
          console.log("MONGODB: Default Connection Established");
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
          process.exit(1);
        }   
     }

   connectDB();
```

Comment: Thank you, yeah its a better approach too.